# vba for deleting a cell content if another cell =FALSE

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am new to VBA and macros. I am trying to delete the contents of `Cell D3` if `Cell B4 = FALSE`. If `Cell B4 = TRUE` then do nothing. This is what I wrote

```
    Range("b3:b4").Calculate
    Range("B4").Select
    If Range = False Then
        Range("D3").Select
        cell.ClearContents
    End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I have the calculate at the beginning because I have the sheet set to manual calculations because I don't want everything recalculate.

Am I way off in what I have written?

Comment: `If [B4] = False Then [D3] = ""`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Sub Demo()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'set calculation mode to automatic
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")  'change Sheet2 to your data sheet

    'check condition for B4=FALSE
    If Not ws.Range("B4") Then ws.Range("D3").ClearContents
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual   'set calculation mode to manual
End Sub
```

**NOTE :** Use of `SELECT` should be avoided. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) for details.

***EDIT :*** As @Slai pointed out in the comment below, `If Not ws.Range("B4")` will return `TRUE` if text of `Range("B4")`is either `False`, `0` or  (blank). So either you'll have to make sure that only `TRUE` and `FLASE` are entered in `Cell B4` else add another `IF` condition in code to check whether the entered value is `BOOLEAN` or not. Thus update above code as

```
Sub Demo()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 'set calculation mode to automatic
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")  'change Sheet2 to your data sheet

    If VarType(ws.Range("B4")) = vbBoolean Then 'check whether the cell value is boolean
        'check condition for B4=FALSE
        If Not ws.Range("B4") Then ws.Range("D3").ClearContents
    End If
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual   'set calculation mode to manual
End Sub
```

Comment: `If ws.Range("B4") = False Then` might be better, because `ws.Range("B4")` can also evaluate to False if it's 0 or Empty

Comment: @Slai - Thanks for pointing that out, but if I am not wrong `If ws.Range("B4") = False Then` will also be `TRUE` if `ws.Range("B4")=0` so instead `ws.Range("B4") = "False"` should be used.

Comment: @Nina - See EDIT in answer.

Comment: sorry I overcomplicated it :] I was pretty sure that `0 = False` and `"" = False` would result in False, but don't have Excel to test it.

Comment: @Slai - Even I didn't check it for blanks and 0's. In fact your comment helped me to work on it other way around, So thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try Mrig's code. However, I think you may want to know how your code doesn't work. I think the problem is in :

1) If Range = False Then -> Please change it to: If Selection = False Then

2)cell.ClearContents -> Please change it to:   Selection.ClearContents

3) Delete the last "End if", because it is excessive.

Comment: Use of `SELECT` should be avoided. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Thank you for telling me where my own code was wrong.  It is great to learn this stuff rather than just copying and pasting someone else's work.

Answer (score 0):

**Mrig** already gave you a solution, but to help you in the future you should know that the default property for a range is "value", so you can (as Mrig) test directly against it. ( Ie. *If Not ws.Range("B4")* is the same as *"If Not ws.Range("B4").Value"* ). Also there is no need to select the range/cell before accessing its methods, so you can do "*Range("D3").ClearContents*" without first selecting the cell(s), as long as you have no other reason to select or activate a range.

P.s Values in cells are (unless otherwise stated, with "Option Compare Text" or converting cell values) case sensitive when tested, so it's a good practice to use a same consistent capitalization with ranges too, helps reading the code too.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  It is working great, just like I wanted it to.